# Server-side printf() isn't printing without "\n" (TCP client-server using sockets)

Tags: c, sockets, tcp

Practicing C network programming: I am writing a simple TCP client-server application that is supposed to send a menu (in a separate thread for each client) as a string from the server to the client and print the menu on the client side (latter on this will become a console shop app). Client should then send a int (the selected option from the menu) and the server should receive it but the server doesn't even print an error. Server side:

```
// Returning message to client
if ( write (tdL.cl, &size_firstLoginMenu, sizeof(int)) <= 0 ) {
    printf("[Thread %d] ",tdL.idThread);
    perror ("[Thread] Error at write(): size_firstLoginMenu to client.\n");
}
if (write (tdL.cl, firstLoginMenu, size_firstLoginMenu) <= 0) {
    printf("[Thread %d] ",tdL.idThread);
    perror ("[Thread] Error at write(): firstLoginMenu to client.\n");
} else {
    printf ("[Thread %d] Message firstLoginMenu was sent succesfully.\n",tdL.idThread);
}

// Reading the client's selected option 
int selectedOption; 
if (read(tdL.cl, &selectedOption, sizeof(int)) <= 0) {
    printf("[Thread %d]\n",tdL.idThread);
    perror ("Error at read() from client.\n");
}
printf("Message from clinet, selectedOption: %d", selectedOption);
```

Unfortunately neither of the last two prints show in the server console, I am sending **selectedOption** in the last part of the client:

```
// Reading size of first mesage: lenWelcomeMsg
if (read(sd, &lenWelcomeMsg, sizeof(int)) < 0) {
    perror ("[client] Error reading len welcome message from server.\n");
}
// Reading initial message from server: welcomeMessageFromServer
if (readAll(sd, welcomeMessageFromServer, lenWelcomeMsg) < 0) {
    perror ("[client] Error reading welcome message from server.\n");
    return errno;
}
// Initial menu - Login Sign Up - message
char initialMenu[512];
int len_initialMenu;
// Reading size of first mesage: lenWelcomeMsg
if (read(sd, &len_initialMenu, sizeof(int)) < 0) {
    perror ("[client] Error reading len_initialMenu from server.\n");
}
// Reading initial menu - Login Sign Up - message from server: initialMenu
if (readAll(sd, initialMenu, len_initialMenu) < 0) {
    perror ("[client] Error reading initialMenu message from server.\n");
    return errno;
}

printf("%s",welcomeMessageFromServer);
printf("\n");
printf("%s",initialMenu);
printf("\n\nSelect your option...\n");

// Sending message containing client selected option to the server  
if (write (sd, &selectedOption,sizeof(int)) <= 0) {
  perror ("[client] Error at write() selectedOption from client to server.\n");
  return errno;
}
```

Clinet side output:

```
Welcome to Console Shopper!

1. Login.
2. Sign Up.


Select your option... 1
```

Sever side output:

```
[Thread 0] Sending Welcome message to client:
Welcome to Console Shopper!
[Thread 0] Message initMsgToClient was sent succesfully.
[Thread 0] Sending first menu message to client:
1. Login.
2. Sign Up.
[Thread 0] Message firstLoginMenu was sent succesfully.
```

I was expecting for at least an error as I am treating the `if (read() <= 0)` but nothing bellow `int selectedOption;` gets printed.

**UPDATE:** Found a solution: adding a `\n` inside last `printf` on server fixes the issue, I am still confused why would a simple `\n` cause the server to stop printing, and would appreciate if anyone would take the time to explain me why is this so. I am referring to:

```
printf("Message from clinet, selectedOption: %d\n", selectedOption);
                       -------------------------^
```

Answer (score 1):

> adding a `\n` inside last `printf` on server fixes the issue, I am still confused why would a simple `\n` cause the server to stop printing, and would appreciate if anyone would take the time to explain me why is this so.

What you observe is `stdout` buffering in the standard C library, see [`man stdout`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/stdout.3.html):

> The stream `stderr` is unbuffered. The stream `stdout` is line-buffered when it points to a terminal. Partial lines will not appear until `fflush(3)` or `exit(3)` is called, or a newline is printed.